# Traveling for a Conference

Tags: usa, international-travel, children

I am hoping to go to the USA to attend a nursing conference. I am trying to improve my standards and learn from the conference for a better working knowledge of nursing and all related field.

Can I also attend the nursing conference in America and take my grandchild along with me?

Comment: Where are you from? Do  you and your grandchild have B1/B2 Visa?

Comment: Yes you can if you’re both approved for the visa. Who will provide childcare? Be ready for such questions during your interview.

Comment: Why would you bring a child to a conference? I can't see that ever being appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you’re both approved for the visa or ESTA as the case may be. Who will provide childcare? Be ready for such questions during your visa interview.

If you're both eligible for ESTA, you can travel for an ESTA if approved in which case no interview. Remember to have travel authorization from the parents of your grandchild or your documents to prove you're the guardian.